# Parachain didn't produce blocks

Tags: parachain, learning

[image]
While im running the parachain , its not not producing any blocks, but its showing the stat collation in logs. im using docker containers for running relay and parachains. polkadot v1.0.0 and pokadot-parachain:1.0.0  image

Comment: explain a bit more